# Where is this still of a Caitian admiral from?

Tags: star-trek, the-voyage-home

When searching for pictures of the Star Trek species "Caitian", I'll always find this picture of a Caitian admiral, which appeared in "Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home":

[image]

*(Memory Alpha page for this image: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/File:Caitian-brown.jpg)*

However, watching both the scenes that are set in the Federation council at the beginning and the end of the movie, I cannot find a take where this still could be taken from.

Is it from another version of the movie (e.g. Director's Cut) or from some special feature with additional scenes? Is there a version of this image with higher resolution?

Comment: I believe it's a set shot rather than an grab from the film